# Typing a React component with a prop determining its final props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, intellisense

I have a component with a prop `as`, this prop can be any component such as tagname (e.g div), function components or class component and it will determine any additional props that can be given to my component. But I'm facing an error when giving any additional prop that isn't defined inside the MenuItemProps type. The default value for the `as` prop is the Link component from react-router-dom.

```
interface MenuItemType {
  (props: MenuItemProps): JSX.Element;
}
```

```
type MenuItemProps = {
  as?: ElementType;
  className?: ClassValue;
  icon?: ReactNode;
  title?: ReactNode;
};
```

```
const MenuItem: MenuItemType = ({
  as: Component = Link,
  className,
  icon,
  title,
  ...props
}) => (
  <Component
    {...props}
    className={clsx(
      className,
      "rounded-lg w-full group p-2 flex gap-2 items-center hover:bg-[#fafafa] dark:hover:bg-neutral-800"
    )}
  >...
```

I have tried using generics but I can't write one properly.
There's no suggestion of props for the value of `as` prop in VS Code.

```
(property) to: string
Type '{ to: string; title: any; icon: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MenuItemProps'.
  Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MenuItemProps'.
```

Comment: [Please include error information as text, not as a picture of text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've included the error message